Jenkins- Plugin Not compatible after downgrade
We upgraded Jenkins to 2.4.62 post which we realized we don't have compatible java version to support. We downgraded it to 2.2.64 post which Jenkins is not showing any Jobs or anything, we took hudson backup but it is also not working( says the error file is used by another process).
Currently Jenkins shows GIT and many other plugins are not compatible with downgraded version. Any help is appreciated as I am new to Jenkins.
We want all build history and jobs to show up in Jenkins UI again. The jobs,pipelines were set up by people who are not with us anymore.
